# activemodel serializer has_one with custom root name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a `has_one` relationship in my serializer but setting `root: :some_other_root` doesn't seem to make any difference. I see in the doc they are only using a different `root` name with `has_many`. So the question is is it possible to have a different root name on `has_one` ?

given:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_one :address, root: :primary_address
end
```

returns:

```
{"user":{"id": 12, "address":{"id":5,"company_name":"widgets co"}}}
```

expected:

```
{"user":{"id": 12, "primary_address":{"id":5,"company_name":"widgets co"}}}
```

Comment: try `key` instead of `root`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `key` instead of `root` if it will be included as part of the user attributes.  There's a [thorough explanation on how to embed associations](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#associations) in the gem repo. The example looks like this:

> **In Serializer:** `attribute :title, key: :name`
>   **#attributes:** `{ name: 'Some Title' }`